# On the derivation of the fundamental lemma of the combinatorial sieve

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Let $b(d)$ be multiplicative function defined on squarefree numbers such that

$$
r_\mathcal A(d)=|\mathcal A_d|-{b(d)\over d}X
$$

relatively small, and $P(z)$ is the product of primes in $\mathcal P\cap[2,z)$. If there exists $\kappa,A>0$ such that whenever $2\le w<z$

$$
\prod_{\substack{p\in\mathcal P\\w\le p<z}}\left(1-{b(p)\over p}\right)^{-1}\le\left(\log z\over\log w\right)^\kappa\left(1+{A\over\log w}\right)
$$

then the fundamental lemma of the combinatorial sieve states that

$$
S(\mathcal A,\mathcal P,z)=XV(z)\left\{1+\mathcal O(u^{-u/2})\right\}+\theta\sum_{\substack{d|P(z)\\d<z^u}}|r_\mathcal A(d)|\tag1
$$

where $|\theta|\le1$,

$$
V(z)=\prod_{\substack{p\in\mathcal P\\p<z}}\left(1-{b(p)\over p}\right)
$$

and the $\mathcal O$-constant may depend on $\kappa$ and $A$.

The first time I encounter this is from Tenenbaum's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, which states that an expository account of this technology is available in Halberstam & Richert's *Sieve Methods*. Nevertheless, after reading through this literature, I did not find any types of fundamental lemma similar to (1). Thus, I look up Diamond & Halberstam's *A Higher-Dimensional Sieve Method* but only found a version of fundamental lemma with the remainder term of Selberg's sieve (see Theorem 4.1 of that book):

$$
S(\mathcal A,\mathcal P,z)=XV(z)\left\{1+\mathcal O(e^{-u\log u-3u/2})\right\}+\theta\sum_{\substack{d|P(z)\\d<z^{2u}}}3^{\omega(d)}|r_\mathcal A(d)|\tag2
$$

Thus, I would love to know where I can find a full derivation of the fundamental lemma as presented in (1).

Comment: i don't know, but often when i find something a pain to look for in halberstam and richert i look for it in greaves' book:)

Comment: Depending on how large you want your u to be, this looks similar to equation (2.16) in Halberstam-Richert. Note that they have used their condition (R) to take care of the remainder there.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite I have read the book you referenced before asking this question.. I would prefer a general version that truncates the remainder term as stated in my answer.